# Fastest downscaling of 8bit gray image with SSE

Tags: c++, image-processing, x86, sse, simd

I have a function which downscales an 8-Bit image by a factor of two. I have previously [optimised the rgb32 case with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052040/fastest-50-scaling-of-argb32-images-using-sse-intrinsics). Now I would like to do the same for the gray8 case.

At the core, there is a function taking two lines of pixel data, which works like this:

```
/** 
 * Calculates the average of two rows of gray8 pixels by averaging four pixels.
 */
void average2Rows(const uint8_t* row1, const uint8_t* row2, uint8_t* dst, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 2)
        *(dst++) = ((row1[i]+row1[i+1]+row2[i]+row2[i+1])/4)&0xFF;
}
```

Now, I have come up with an SSE variant which is about three times faster, but it does involve a lot of shuffling and I think one might do better. Does anybody see what can be optimised here?

```
/* row1: 16 8-bit values A-P
 * row2: 16 8-bit values a-p
 * returns 16 8-bit values (A+B+a+b)/4, (C+D+c+d)/4, ..., (O+P+o+p)/4
 */
__m128i avg16Bytes(const __m128i& row1, const __m128i& row2)
{
    static const __m128i  zero = _mm_setzero_si128(); 

    __m128i ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP = _mm_avg_epu8(row1_u8, row2);

    __m128i ABCDEFGH  = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP, zero);
    __m128i IJKLMNOP  = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP, zero);

    __m128i AIBJCKDL = _mm_unpacklo_epi16( ABCDEFGH, IJKLMNOP );
    __m128i EMFNGOHP = _mm_unpackhi_epi16( ABCDEFGH, IJKLMNOP );

    __m128i AEIMBFJN = _mm_unpacklo_epi16( AIBJCKDL, EMFNGOHP );
    __m128i CGKODHLP = _mm_unpackhi_epi16( AIBJCKDL, EMFNGOHP );

    __m128i ACEGIKMO = _mm_unpacklo_epi16( AEIMBFJN, CGKODHLP );
    __m128i BDFHJLNP = _mm_unpackhi_epi16( AEIMBFJN, CGKODHLP );

    return _mm_avg_epu8(ACEGIKMO, BDFHJLNP);
}

/*
 * Calculates the average of two rows of gray8 pixels by averaging four pixels.
 */
void average2Rows(const uint8_t* src1, const uint8_t* src2, uint8_t* dst, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<size-31; i+=32)
    {
        __m128i tl = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i const*)(src1+i));
        __m128i tr = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i const*)(src1+i+16));
        __m128i bl = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i const*)(src2+i));
        __m128i br = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i const*)(src2+i+16)))

        __m128i l_avg = avg16Bytes(tl, bl);
        __m128i r_avg = avg16Bytes(tr, br);

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)(dst+(i/2)), _mm_packus_epi16(l_avg, r_avg));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I realise my function has slight (off by one) rounding errors, but I am  willing to accept this.
- For clarity I have assumed size is a multiple of 32.

EDIT: There is now a [github repository](https://github.com/bjornpiltz/halfsize_sse_benchmark) implementing the answers to this question. The fastest solution was provided by user [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes). See his essay below for details:

```
__m128i avg16Bytes(const __m128i& row1, const __m128i& row2)
{
    // Average the first 16 values of src1 and src2:
    __m128i avg = _mm_avg_epu8(row1, row2);

    // Unpack and horizontal add:
    avg = _mm_maddubs_epi16(avg, _mm_set1_epi8(1));

    // Divide by 2:
    return  _mm_srli_epi16(avg, 1);
}
```

It works as my original implementation by calculating `(a+b)/2 + (c+d)/2` as opposed to `(a+b+c+d)/4`, so it has the same off-by-one rounding error.

Cudos to user [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) for implementing a solution which is twice as fast as mine, but exact:

```
__m128i avg16Bytes(const __m128i& row1, const __m128i& row2)
{
    // Unpack and horizontal add:
    __m128i row1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(row1_u8, _mm_set1_epi8(1));
    __m128i row2 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(row2_u8, _mm_set1_epi8(1));

    // vertical add:
    __m128i avg = _mm_add_epi16(row1_avg, row2_avg);              

    // divide by 4:
    return _mm_srli_epi16(avg, 2);                     
}
```

Comment: To avg16Bytes, load 16 bytes to a register and shift a copy one byte to the left. Average both and clear every other byte, then pack words to bytes. (Even better to clear and pack after averaging with the next row).

Comment: I have tried to implement this approach here: https://github.com/bjornpiltz/halfsize_sse_benchmark/blob/master/main.cpp#L106 and it does improve on the original version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to accept double-rounding from using `pavgb` twice, you can go faster than Paul R's answer by doing the vertical averaging first with `pavgb`, cutting in half the amount of data that needs to be unpacked to 16-bit elements.  (And allowing half the loads to fold into memory operands for `pavgb`, reducing front-end bottlenecks on some CPUs.)

For horizontal averaging, your best bet is probably still `pmaddubsw` with `set1(1)` and shift by 1, then pack.

```
// SSSE3 version
// I used `__restrict__` to give the compiler more flexibility in unrolling
void average2Rows_doubleround(const uint8_t* __restrict__ src1, const uint8_t*__restrict__ src2,
                              uint8_t*__restrict__ dst, size_t size)
{
    const __m128i vk1 = _mm_set1_epi8(1);
    size_t dstsize = size/2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dstsize - 15; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i v0 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)&src1[i*2]);
        __m128i v1 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)&src1[i*2 + 16]);
        __m128i v2 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)&src2[i*2]);
        __m128i v3 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)&src2[i*2 + 16]);
        __m128i left  = _mm_avg_epu8(v0, v2);
        __m128i right = _mm_avg_epu8(v1, v3);

        __m128i w0 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(left, vk1);        // unpack and horizontal add
        __m128i w1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(right, vk1);
        w0 = _mm_srli_epi16(w0, 1);                     // divide by 2
        w1 = _mm_srli_epi16(w1, 1);
        w0 = _mm_packus_epi16(w0, w1);                  // pack

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i], w0);
    }
}
```

The other option is `_mm_srli_epi16(v, 8)` to line up the odd elements with the even elements of every horizontal pair.  But since there is no horizontal pack with truncation, you have to `_mm_and_si128(v, _mm_set1_epi16(0x00FF))` both halves before you pack.  It turns out to be slower than using SSSE3 `pmaddubsw`, especially without AVX where it takes extra MOVDQA instructions to copy registers.

```
void average2Rows_doubleround_SSE2(const uint8_t* __restrict__ src1, const uint8_t* __restrict__ src2, uint8_t* __restrict__ dst, size_t size)
{
    size /= 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 15; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i v0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i*2]);
        __m128i v1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i*2 + 16]);
        __m128i v2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i*2]);
        __m128i v3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i*2 + 16]);
        __m128i left  = _mm_avg_epu8(v0, v2);
        __m128i right = _mm_avg_epu8(v1, v3);

        __m128i l_odd  = _mm_srli_epi16(left, 8);   // line up horizontal pairs
        __m128i r_odd  = _mm_srli_epi16(right, 8);

        __m128i l_avg = _mm_avg_epu8(left, l_odd);  // leaves garbage in the high halves
        __m128i r_avg = _mm_avg_epu8(right, r_odd);

        l_avg = _mm_and_si128(l_avg, _mm_set1_epi16(0x00FF));
        r_avg = _mm_and_si128(r_avg, _mm_set1_epi16(0x00FF));
        __m128i avg   = _mm_packus_epi16(l_avg, r_avg);          // pack
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i], avg);
    }
}
```

With AVX512BW, there's `_mm_cvtepi16_epi8`, but IACA says it's 2 uops on Skylake-AVX512, and it only takes 1 input and produces a half-width output.  According to IACA, the memory-destination form is 4 total unfused-domain uops (same as reg,reg + separate store).  I had to use [`_mm_mask_cvtepi16_storeu_epi8(&dst\[i+0\], -1, l_avg);`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=5170,1341,1350&text=movwb) to get it, because gcc and clang fail to fold a separate `_mm_store` into a memory destination for `vpmovwb`.  (There is no non-masked store intrinsic, because compilers are supposed to do that for you like they do with folding `_mm_load` into memory operands for typical ALU instructions).

It's probably only useful when narrowing to 1/4 or 1/8th (`cvtepi64_epi8`), not just in half.  Or maybe useful to avoid needing a second shuffle to deal with the in-lane behaviour of `_mm512_packus_epi16`.  With AVX2, after a `_mm256_packus_epi16` on `[D C] [B A]`, you have `[D B | C A]`, which you can fix with an AVX2 `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64 (__m256i a, const int imm8)` to shuffle in 64-bit chunks.  But with AVX512, you'd need a vector shuffle-control for the `vpermq`.  `packus` + a fixup shuffle is probably still a better option, though.

---

Once you do this, there aren't many vector instructions left in the loop, and **there's a lot to gain from letting the compiler make tighter asm**.  Your loop is unfortunately difficult for compilers to do a good job with.
  (This also helps Paul R's solution, since he copied the compiler-unfriendly loop structure from the question.)

**Use the loop-counter in a way that gcc/clang can optimize better**, and use types that avoid re-doing sign extension every time through the loop.

With your current loop, gcc/clang actually do an arithmetic right-shift for `i/2`, instead of incrementing by 16 (instead of 32) and using scaled-index addressing modes for the loads.  It seems they don't realize that `i` is always even.

[(full code + asm on Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIBSAJgGY8AO2QAbZlgDU3fgGEGBfKgB0CGdm4AGAIJ9BI8VJnzFovACNV6rboHCxEzNLl4Atq%2BEFiwq/w069e0MnYwV8IQJff10dADdUPHRJAENYzGJk4ExeACVUAHcGAH10FnNRdJYhdAg0IQVJZk8ADiKCACpJBjZ6STqGpojWjq62XlJGlrbO9AUJhjwAL0w2rqXMAEobbgB2ACEbSSO%2B1HqCSSKi11peZrxJWIBrWmcAEQv3IoZMAloizAADnhmhBaFt%2BAcdMc1stJAB6GTvXgySHaaEAMxIkggC2Wq3uiMkmhRkgJchhTgAtJJaABWEkE3gHfjvWgANi2UOOu1R0Ohl2ut3usU0bw%2BriKolQyXQXzwNxBEAFCvu7S2vDZ3WQtG4tL2eHayNpr3BvL5R2VQoeL0JVwlUplcoVUEtd0kar4mp6uv1hukTJpbN1JpRh3NFyuKoevDFdsl0tlC2dSsjVo9Gq1Rt9RpDELD5tdwv4sc%2BDsT8tuLtTbvTXuQWYNMb4e0DwdN%2Bb5hckFXR5xLEtSwH%2BAOYIJFE1ivHbXIL1fu3mACHOts%2Bg%2BHo4gsV6sX405iaPDXfyopXEtcMvQzHMxUB8rZEB7BAnz1N4fhcMaQgByWQjxS1UkBASCWU4CGSUQUnQdAO35OdJHyG0WXFK4LyvG8gXZCAFyXZ8wVDGc%2BWPfsvmIMxhzvCBjwmPCITfOjoThD98FiRInHMABPSRkQI6EEOI7oyNvTCEOovc3yI08im/X9mHQiiqPgmiW3o8NGMkaTHm2HjjjjBQSEwZgnUrFNBRrdU2VmAgfTwYMJmPMTuR2V5ticrTtDUgBZTi0mIBZTkaBYhGALjJGIKpZkkVB0XUwdzAmcxmHOfJCAQSQCAQJxhEwdF0TwZA8EwCJu1QVAAS6LxmGQAhWEwGx4kSFIfMybI8kKEoygqMLmGqeNStQHyMplWpTgGKYRi1Xp%2BnOQYCGGTpMwmGa5skSyJk8ClOV0fYOymiNTOFZ5%2BJ%2BP5bxBJSO0Y3EnARJDkTzAjMWIbF1rJd5iVoslZApSRqX4HUPv9Zl3n4KcOx5GCdLgkViLLQyk2Mrtawm6y23wg9Z3260YYTOGK0VRHzORvVGRbdlUfu9HOyhpskLjWGjPxuCkbGFHjQcjGox3bGZVx5MCc9TNrMB1s2bRt8u0fI5JLXQEN3HaN2apzHsOXWnV1iIdZbHbddzRiGLTgiS1bPVDr3IzDH1w19VI/bqNP/JIgO8RZQPAyDoO0g3Mb4yTzygtDzfvFWrbF8MjfeXTSLwQPKM0USSRUui1OY1jJA4rj9cU/io5jkSaUV3iT2NqSf0eWTc7jxTrcThiPw0tzxc%2BPTiAMhmq0x2tLOsuEczszRFd2ZyAlcgJR/3eqklSdJmtyApim/ZhRGIYazkmIZplGbUJl2paN4WtfZo31bPwWYAhEwJIrs28GCN2rsnkQiOm%2BO8izr3C64Su%2BFCTus0jke7EV18Rinei2T631fr/TAYDQkINNrQhvpTWCmNoaSXpvDRmHdCbemJuTP%2BStOaP2QugvG7cozM21ELZsItcz4OQZzGmT97Q4zbiZch2D6ys1oZne%2BxY0EsIwWQtMHCGzCzJqLCmPDDZFyYShf2ZshL3nlg/aufI1J21Lg7QCwEXYRDdheKR3siFxj9peBRGElHbhfKHDmVp8iMOQqYgOijNzjAeNYim4tDZ8OLk48xFEdwh0kZ7eCMjkIXgrnZUGtEa42weOkAgeV9FQUzj7YuESXF53yLrYJSDjjh2QgJaOmTK7ROUrEtRTE8AsSkOnAALKk4xTcc6ZN6GUhuYcwlxg0uXEpdklIVOOGpeuY9G4Smbq3QRbDhGei7sTeEGdjR9wHiPLaQ99x1QSJPJqWRZ5tVKFeTq4UigAGUTnYF4CvUa69xo9G3iNaaY15pjEWk8lacwKSrCvi5fBjE75Q0OpJb4vxX6gkVl/G6SIbGSAATidYwDCSgNJM4L6X9qR0gZDApC7J4GOToZDFBXTSwJlYfzDMODsx4MMYQ7m5Y%2BZMw4TqYmfpqHiO4SE%2B%2BDi6YkqmWSusDZDRUo5VDHxsiyykoZQLFmzKmwBjZe/TQABOCW2U%2BzSw1uuMcldJwKuVXBFWxEZYjm1hOHJqItJ6sxqIIoGAkjZ0EhYh8qqJjNGrmpMw59GhlSdiBPREFvx4F8harsxAbVQSlsXIpMdg6SFdXrUelqozWsHIajVWsnW9gmNa211t3WYCngwSQwBkjEHMM1UkQg0oZUAngRcgFwJpAYMG/VRQU3qs1sarCtacKhTDegBVthBDRR1Am5NGtDU9UEWO4AExdIvxcZoAAHpoTQAAxVdGxdWhrbekydpDt0a1nc/EFC7l1ro3bqrsKaI2yJ6XJC2rbD29sHKo80wzS48KbkQFuvMEaSo1HM/UtlGrAHfgITAohvjvgjNoAAagADVpDcPYAB1S4Ng1IABUEB4ELfkU4YBODnEwGkSt5gnDomSAodIkVK0nIANIABlKTwYwwiJVJiqOPCKMgWIBBFFfG/a3U6EBZkKBRkyYkSyfq9GnXuRiWhlWfHPAwbjvH%2BMWME/pQyImxNWVwUyZowHKS9APaBvW4Hqh4HRGDVZg83KbIalPDIuzWrFBbuiK5jybmdDCnnHeby/NuN3iMY%2BQDzjfOHvg2F4XkWIsxcYCBNIEtMh/riqW20QmAfuB%2BHMYosIFCZUB40ws/NFZJslkr1CgtcNKwUURrK2wLIaZ4xy6z7Nj3WueYQEBr6ZcprtdalbCS0E0LwFr5qCLgVrUIKjEA4EH2GJvIrQhgzQum2fObC2QubyzKt4062zCbYYPNqci3VhYAUEUDzPpK25bW61o4G3Zsne22NFamArv8fE3qO7iznK5IxFiCAL0QEJfJKt2izZmx4HS9Ifrb4ibFfeISDI1RevQuhILXBVWkJo5qCs9rD1geg/iwDRLf3f4wKZLD2z%2BKjiXYINd7KtXEWLuSMkTHxxGdtE%2B/p5HIDF20npI9%2BHRPKbOZnm55nnmJrzBeR9q7HmJhCEVrC9aLcASFsRc4FsmvtfklGyu43K7dehUBE21LTI4fQkl65ue7VDmVG6jUOXu2Jg8%2B%2B0%2BSQqv42U3V0VV6RJwdfUpySaHNO4eILfNZ7EyRrwQE93z2r1Iec3ZxyaZw2B86Z2jypAE3gIieb4LwGyLI%2BC0nQCAf0tJmA17rxXhvvBa/V482KRvEwvft%2Bb8wXUshVu8DcXgeXlC9Qxk6DZaTSPx9xblcB7HewZ%2BT9eCPrMS%2BxHAbTyzjPHu%2Be85%2B8jgubXbPi%2BhC3aqxBK2gJcuLzgGxSCiC4LSTgpAhBcE0C/1AXBZAR5bEwVg7A/of0L%2BBA7%2Bd%2B9%2BjwIA/AdSygzQiqdSIMwuiqtIzQqBmg9Aj%2BnAdSL%2Bb%2BnAH%2BpAX%2BnAL%2BDAIAccoBeBd%2BpAcAsASAaArgQInU5AlAdBDB6QIAwAbI/ApAuUog/GvklAlwRQmglA9%2B5gYBpAdBrghUBAAA8kIKIOxOIfgC3FVNUp9uIZ4BBuIVQAAI7MDpCKGcD8DKC8DKC0Av4VBBTpR0CkAF4kYyHmBUCYBVQCGXDCFwqLCLAVB0hja0BwFIaKrQH8CUAu7ZRZRV5OpZDVDwC0ikBxycDmGbqboP6FTADWH0B2GxAOFOEuEphCGUBUAACK%2BhxA7EIMo2bIOwbIdSOwzQnBY2dSSGo2vAtAlA%2BADAAIogyQhhlBuIXhmAPhLR/htAgRCBIR1QYR58ERFQURVekAsR8RiRSRKRVhSAYIyRpUiSI0XAlIKG4EEEP0YQiIZ8veVuewtALwlIMhxYlI54bAagLIDAyQ1Q7E5g3g6AWQP0rgDAPxmAxYXxQgqAlIqQi6xBLAbAHAYID%2BT%2BOB4hhBi6dRlI1RRayAyAkgbIygxYEAuAhAWIegvQsgqA9BeAnUQBYIIBYByRkBIMygbIvAiqmgOwmgdRIxdI8B0JWBL%2BrgdAK6r%2BcJXAxBpBpA5BH%2B9%2B1BiAKARJrBZAFAw0xJnUKAXRQUdSvJPBfBJBeR7hoh4hkh0hchChShgazhiSjaGhEQWhFBpAuhJRhhxhph5hKxaRaxthLcWRjhxprh%2BRHh/RgxfhyBIxQR4xWAuUUxlAMxhUcxoIccix4ByRlhTpNhmR2RHpmpBRxRBh5RmglR1RtR9R42TRvhbRuGnR3RAp9%2BfR3htIvhwxoxwREAoRIZF8YZmAsx8Ao2cRpACRsZ9%2B8Z6RyxmxeA2xnAlIYQZg5giIY5yAv%2BP0exogEEI5igxxQgpxBwTIFxP01xXxJayADxrwqm7EXRjwVIrggJwJsQoJjA4J7AdAPZMJfJlp8JiJyJYgzxwUMBmgygoo2J%2BA36ZJEwhJ8pNGegU4FJFBVJUBphNRbIbImg/AtIdSLRiqMFOwHJ2B95%2BBhBgpZBlJt5nAvAXJPJccuBGFApwpOFpAPkfkb%2BdSQAA%3D):

```
.LBB1_2:     ## clang's inner loop for int i, dst[i/2] version
    movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdi + rcx]
    movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + rcx + 16]
    movdqu  xmm3, xmmword ptr [rsi + rcx]
    movdqu  xmm4, xmmword ptr [rsi + rcx + 16]
    pavgb   xmm3, xmm1
    pavgb   xmm4, xmm2
    pmaddubsw       xmm3, xmm0
    pmaddubsw       xmm4, xmm0
    psrlw   xmm3, 1
    psrlw   xmm4, 1
    packuswb        xmm3, xmm4

    mov     eax, ecx         # This whole block is wasted instructions!!!
    shr     eax, 31
    add     eax, ecx
    sar     eax              # eax = ecx/2, with correct rounding even for negative `i`
    cdqe                     # sign-extend EAX into RAX

    movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdx + rax], xmm3
    add     rcx, 32          # i += 32
    cmp     rcx, r8
    jl      .LBB1_2          # }while(i < size-31)
```

gcc7.1 isn't quite so bad, (just `mov`/`sar`/`movsx`), but gcc5.x and 6.x do separate pointer-increments for src1 and src2, and also for a counter/index for the stores.  (Totally braindead behaviour, especially since they still do it with `-march=sandybridge`.  Indexed `movdqu` stores and non-indexed `movdqu` loads gives you the maximum loop overhead.)

Anyway, using `dstsize` and multiplying `i` inside the loop instead of dividing it gives much better results.  Different versions of gcc and clang reliably compile it into a single loop-counter that they use with a scaled-index addressing mode for the loads.  You get code like:

```
    movdqa  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdi + 2*rax]
    movdqa  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + 2*rax + 16]
    pavgb   xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 2*rax]
    pavgb   xmm2, xmmword ptr [rsi + 2*rax + 16]   # saving instructions with aligned loads, see below
    ...
    movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdx + rax], xmm1
    add     rax, 16
    cmp     rax, rcx
    jb      .LBB0_2
```

I used `size_t i` to match `size_t` size, to make sure gcc didn't waste any instructions sign-extending or zero-extending it to the width of a pointer.  (zero-extension usually happens for free, though, so `unsigned size` and `unsigned i` might have been ok, and saved a couple REX prefixes.)

You could still get rid of the `cmp` but counting an index up towards 0, which would speed the loop up a little bit more than what I've done.  I'm not sure how easy it would be to get compilers to not be stupid and omit the `cmp` instruction if you do count up towards zero.  Indexing from the end of an object is no problem, though. `src1+=size;`.  It does complicate things if you want to use an unaligned-cleanup loop, though.

---

On my Skylake i7-6700k (max turbo 4.4GHz, but look at the clock-cycle counts rather than times).  With g++7.1, this makes a difference of ~2.7 seconds for 100M reps of 1024 bytes vs. ~3.3 seconds.

```
 Performance counter stats for './grayscale-dowscale-by-2.inline.gcc-skylake-noavx' (2 runs):

   2731.607950      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.40% )
             2      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                    ( +- 20.00% )
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            88      page-faults:u             #    0.032 K/sec                    ( +-  0.57% )
11,917,723,707      cycles                    #    4.363 GHz                      ( +-  0.07% )
42,006,654,015      instructions              #    3.52  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
41,908,837,143      uops_issued_any           # 15342.186 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
49,409,631,052      uops_executed_thread      # 18088.112 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
 3,301,193,901      branches                  # 1208.517 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
   100,013,629      branch-misses             #    3.03% of all branches          ( +-  0.01% )

   2.731715466 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.40% )
```

vs. Same vectorization, but **with `int i` and `dst[i/2]` creating higher loop overhead** (more scalar instructions):

```
 Performance counter stats for './grayscale-dowscale-by-2.loopoverhead-aligned-inline.gcc-skylake-noavx' (2 runs):

   3314.335833      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.02% )
             4      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                    ( +- 14.29% )
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            88      page-faults:u             #    0.026 K/sec                    ( +-  0.57% )
14,531,925,552      cycles                    #    4.385 GHz                      ( +-  0.06% )
51,607,478,414      instructions              #    3.55  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
51,109,303,460      uops_issued_any           # 15420.677 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
55,810,234,508      uops_executed_thread      # 16839.040 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
 3,301,344,602      branches                  #  996.080 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
   100,025,451      branch-misses             #    3.03% of all branches          ( +-  0.00% )

   3.314418952 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.02% )
```

**vs. Paul R's version (optimized for lower loop overhead)**: exact but slower

```
Performance counter stats for './grayscale-dowscale-by-2.paulr-inline.gcc-skylake-noavx' (2 runs):

   3751.990587      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.03% )
             3      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            88      page-faults:u             #    0.024 K/sec                    ( +-  0.56% )
16,323,525,446      cycles                    #    4.351 GHz                      ( +-  0.04% )
58,008,101,634      instructions              #    3.55  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
57,610,721,806      uops_issued_any           # 15354.709 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
55,505,321,456      uops_executed_thread      # 14793.566 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
 3,301,456,435      branches                  #  879.921 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
   100,001,954      branch-misses             #    3.03% of all branches          ( +-  0.02% )

   3.752086635 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.03% )
```

vs. **Paul R's original version** with extra loop overhead:

```
Performance counter stats for './grayscale-dowscale-by-2.loopoverhead-paulr-inline.gcc-skylake-noavx' (2 runs):

   4154.300887      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.01% )
             3      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            90      page-faults:u             #    0.022 K/sec                    ( +-  1.68% )
18,174,791,383      cycles                    #    4.375 GHz                      ( +-  0.03% )
67,608,724,157      instructions              #    3.72  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
66,937,292,129      uops_issued_any           # 16112.769 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
61,875,610,759      uops_executed_thread      # 14894.350 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
 3,301,571,922      branches                  #  794.736 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
   100,029,270      branch-misses             #    3.03% of all branches          ( +-  0.00% )

   4.154441330 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.01% )
```

Note that branch-misses is about the same as the repeat count: the inner loop mispredicts at the end every time.  Unrolling to keep the loop iteration count under about 22 would make the pattern short enough for Skylake's branch predictors to predict the not-taken condition correctly most of the time.  Branch mispredicts are the only reason we're not getting ~4.0 uops per cycle through the pipeline, so avoiding branch misses would raise the IPC from 3.5 to over 4.0 (cmp/jcc macro-fusion puts 2 instructions in one uop).

These branch-misses probably hurt even if you're bottlenecked on L2 cache bandwidth (instead of the front-end).  I didn't test that, though: my testing just wraps a `for()` loop around the function call from Paul R's test harness, so everything's hot in L1D cache.  32 iterations of the inner loop is close to the worst-case here: low enough for frequent mispredicts, but not so low that branch-prediction can pick up the pattern and avoid them.

My version should run in 3 cycles per iteration, bottlenecked only on the frontend, on Intel Sandybridge and later.  (Nehalem will bottleneck on one load per clock.)

See http://agner.org/optimize/, and also [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) for more about fused-domain vs. unfused-domain uops and perf counters.

---

**update: clang unrolls it for you**, at least when the size is a compile-time constant...  Strangely, it unrolls even the non-inline version of the `dst[i/2]` function (with unknown `size`), but not the lower-loop-overhead version.

With `clang++-4.0 -O3 -march=skylake -mno-avx`, my version (unrolled by 2 by the compiler) runs in: 9.61G cycles for 100M iters (2.2s).  (35.6G uops issued (fused domain), 45.0G uops executed (unfused domain), near-zero branch-misses.)  Probably not bottlenecked on the front-end anymore, but AVX would still hurt.

Paul R's (also unrolled by 2) runs in 12.29G cycles for 100M iters (2.8s).  48.4G uops issued (fused domain), 51.4G uops executed (unfused-domain).  50.1G instructions, for 4.08 IPC, probably still bottlenecked on the front-end (because it needs a couple `movdqa` instructions to copy a register before destroying it).  AVX would help for non-destructive vector instructions, even without AVX2 for wider integer vectors.

With careful coding, you should be able to do about this well for runtime-variable sizes.

---

**Use aligned pointers and aligned loads, so the compiler can use `pavgb` with a memory operand** instead of using a separate unaligned-load instruction.  This means fewer instructions and fewer uops for the front-end, which is a bottleneck for this loop.

This doesn't help Paul's version, because only the second operand for `pmaddubsw` can come from memory, and that's the one treated as signed bytes.  If we used `_mm_maddubs_epi16(_mm_set1_epi8(1), v0);`, the 16-bit multiply result would be sign-extended instead of zero-extended.  So `1+255` would come out to 0 instead of 256.

Folding a load requires alignment with SSE, but not with AVX.  However, [on Intel Haswell/Skylake, indexed addressing modes can only stay micro-fused with instructions which read-modify-write their destination register.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes#comment76198723_31027695)   `vpavgb xmm0, xmm0, [rsi+rax*2]` is un-laminated to 2 uops on Haswell/Skylake before it issues into the out-of-order part of the core, but `pavgb xmm1, [rsi+rax*2]` can stay micro-fused all the way through, so it issues as a single uop.  The front-end issue bottleneck is 4 fused-domain uops per clock on mainstream x86 CPUs except Ryzen (i.e. not Atom/Silvermont).  Folding half the loads into memory operands helps with that on all Intel CPUs except Sandybridge/Ivybridge, and all AMD CPUs.

gcc and clang will fold the loads when inlining into a test function that uses `alignas(32)`, even if you use `_mm_loadu` intrinsics.  They know the data is aligned, and take advantage.

Weird fact: compiling the 128b-vectorized code with AVX code-gen enabled (`-march=native`) actually slows it down on Haswell/Skylake, because it would make all 4 loads issue as separate uops even when they're memory operands for `vpavgb`, and there aren't any `movdqa` register-copying instructions that AVX would avoid.  (Usually AVX comes out ahead anyway even for manually-vectorized code that still only uses 128b vectors, because of the benefit of 3-operand instructions not destroying one of their inputs.)  In this case, `13,53G cycles ( +-  0.05% )` or `3094.195773 ms  ( +-  0.20% )`, up from `11.92G` cycles in ~2.7 seconds.  uops_issued = `48.508G`, up from `41,908`.  Instruction count and uops_executed counts are essentially the same.

OTOH, an actual 256b AVX2 version would run slightly a bit less than twice as fast.  Some unrolling to reduce the front-end bottleneck will definitely help.  An AVX512 version might run close to 4x as fast on Skylake-AVX512 Xeons, but might bottleneck on ALU throughput since SKX shuts down execution port1 when there are any 512b uops in the RS waiting to execute, according to @Mysticial's testing.  (That explains why [`pavgb zmm` has 1 per clock throughput while `pavgb ymm` is 2 per clock.](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt).)

To have both input rows aligned, **store your image data in a format with a row stride that's a multiple of 16**, even if the actual image dimensions are odd.  Your storage stride doesn't have to match your actual image dimensions.

If you can only align either the source or dest (e.g. because you're downscaling a region that starts at an odd column in the source image), you should probably still align your source pointers.

Intel's optimization manual recommends aligning the destination instead of the source, if you can't align both, but doing 4x as many loads as stores probably changes the balance.

To handle unaligned at the start/end, do a potentially-overlapping unaligned vector of pixels from the start and end.  It's fine for stores to overlap other stores, and since dst is separate from src, you can redo a partially-overlapping vector.

In Paul's test `main()`, I just added `alignas(32)` in front of every array.

---

### AVX2:

Since you [compile one version with `-march=native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541530/fastest-downscaling-of-8bit-gray-image-with-sse#comment78083364_45542669), you can easily detect AVX2 at compile time with `#ifdef __AVX2__`.  There's no simple way to use exactly the same code for 128b and 256b manual vectorization.  All the intrinsics have different names, so you typically need to copy everything even if there are no other differences.

(There are some C++ wrapper libraries for the intrinsics that use operator-overloading and function overloading to let you write a templated version that uses the same logic on different widths of vector.  e.g. Agner Fog's VCL is good, but unless your software is open-source, you can't use it because it's GPL licensed and you want to distribute a binary.)

---

To take advantage of AVX2 in your binary-distribution version, you'd have to do runtime detection/dispatching.  In that case, you'd want to dispatch to versions of a function that loops over rows, so you don't have dispatch overhead inside your loop over rows.  Or just let that version use SSSE3.

Comment: You are now the contender https://travis-ci.org/bjornpiltz/halfsize_sse_benchmark/jobs/262180880#L460-L467. Paul is slightly slower, but exact. Now all we need is for John to join ;)

Comment: And thanks for the incredibly detailed post! I will need some time to parse that.

Comment: @bgp2000: On Skylake, my version is significantly faster.  With gcc7.1 11.9G cycles vs. 16.3G cycles for no-AVX mine vs. an optimized version of Paul's.  (Paul's would benefit from AVX, but AVX would hurt mine.  Still, I think mine would be faster even if you tested both with 128b AVX).  If your testing found mine only slightly faster, you're missing out on some relevant CPUs.  (Kaby Lake cores are the same as Skylake, it just uses less power so can run faster.)  SKL/KBL is probably not the majority, but it's worth considering (unless your software is always "fast enough" on new HW).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation which uses fewer instructions. I haven't benchmarked it against your code though, so it may not be significantly faster:

```
void average2Rows(const uint8_t* src1, const uint8_t* src2, uint8_t* dst, int size)
{
    const __m128i vk1 = _mm_set1_epi8(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 31; i += 32)
    {
        __m128i v0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i]);
        __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i + 16]);
        __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i]);
        __m128i v3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i + 16]);

        __m128i w0 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v0, vk1);        // unpack and horizontal add
        __m128i w1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v1, vk1);
        __m128i w2 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v2, vk1);
        __m128i w3 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v3, vk1);

        w0 = _mm_add_epi16(w0, w2);                     // vertical add
        w1 = _mm_add_epi16(w1, w3);

        w0 = _mm_srli_epi16(w0, 2);                     // divide by 4
        w1 = _mm_srli_epi16(w1, 2);

        w0 = _mm_packus_epi16(w0, w1);                  // pack

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i / 2], w0);
    }
}
```

Test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>

void average2Rows_ref(const uint8_t* row1, const uint8_t* row2, uint8_t* dst, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 2)
    {
        dst[i / 2] = (row1[i] + row1[i + 1] + row2[i] + row2[i + 1]) / 4;
    }
}

void average2Rows(const uint8_t* src1, const uint8_t* src2, uint8_t* dst, int size)
{
    const __m128i vk1 = _mm_set1_epi8(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 31; i += 32)
    {
        __m128i v0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i]);
        __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src1[i + 16]);
        __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i]);
        __m128i v3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&src2[i + 16]);

        __m128i w0 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v0, vk1);        // unpack and horizontal add
        __m128i w1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v1, vk1);
        __m128i w2 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v2, vk1);
        __m128i w3 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(v3, vk1);

        w0 = _mm_add_epi16(w0, w2);                     // vertical add
        w1 = _mm_add_epi16(w1, w3);

        w0 = _mm_srli_epi16(w0, 2);                     // divide by 4
        w1 = _mm_srli_epi16(w1, 2);

        w0 = _mm_packus_epi16(w0, w1);                  // pack

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i / 2], w0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 1024;

    uint8_t src1[n];
    uint8_t src2[n];
    uint8_t dest_ref[n / 2];
    uint8_t dest_test[n / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        src1[i] = rand();
        src2[i] = rand();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
    {
        dest_ref[i] = 0xaa;
        dest_test[i] = 0x55;
    }

    average2Rows_ref(src1, src2, dest_ref, n);
    average2Rows(src1, src2, dest_test, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
    {
        if (dest_test[i] != dest_ref[i])
        {
            printf("%u %u %u %u: ref = %u, test = %u\n", src1[2 * i], src1[2 * i + 1], src2[2 * i], src2[2 * i + 1], dest_ref[i], dest_test[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the output of the SIMD version exactly matches the output of the scalar reference code (no "off by one" rounding errors).

Comment: I really appreciate that it is exact! It seems to be slightly faster as well: 1.96 ms vs 1.8.

Comment: `pmaddubsw` (`_mm_maddubs_epi16`) is fairly high latency (5 clocks), so there are probably a few stalls in the above code. There is probably a more efficient solution without using multiply instructions but it was the first idea that came to mind. I'll chew it over for a bit and see if anyone else comes up with anything better in the mean time...

Comment: I've added a github repo to play with. So far it seems your implementation is the fastest: https://travis-ci.org/bjornpiltz/halfsize_sse_benchmark/jobs/261874306#L464-L470.

Comment: Cool - I feel motivated to come up with something faster now! ;-)

Comment: You might want to use a mix of 3 `maddubs` and one pair of unpacklo/hi against zero or something, so you don't bottleneck on either multiply or shuffle throughput.  (I doubt `pmaddubsw` latency is an issue: the loop body is small enough for out-of-order execution to see independent iterations, and even in one iteration you have 4 independent `pmaddubsw`.  It does have one per 0.5c throughput on Skylake, though, vs. one per 1c on Haswell and earlier.)  @bgp2000: what CPUs do you care about tuning for, and are you interested in making an AVX2 version for CPUs that support it?

Comment: We distribute a Windows executable to a diverse set of work stations. Some of which are quite old, so we always disable AVX. Then we have a cluster Linux version that is always compiled with -march=native. It would be nice if it automatically took advantage of available hardware, but it must be optional.

Comment: @bgp2000: note that the code above uses SSSE3, which has been present in Intel CPUs since 2006 - if you need to support CPUs older than that then you'll need to fall back to an SSE2/SSE3 implementation (or maybe even just the scalar code).

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks - I might play with your idea later today if I get some free time.

Comment: @PaulR: since lower-precision double-rounding is ok for the OP, an SSE2 fallback with `_mm_srli_epi16` to align horizontal pairs for another pavgb would work.  (But it's slower than using `pmaddubsw` for horizontal averaging, whether you do it before or after vertical summing)

Comment: @PaulR SSE3 is ok. We don't have anything quite that old:) We just ran into trouble with SSE4.2 popcnt, which I enable conditionally. AVX on Windows is a no go since we get a crash at static inititalization on some computers if we enable it.

Comment: @bgp2000: OK - note the extra `S` though - [SSSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3) (not SSE3) was introduced on Intel CPUs in 2006, but I'm not sure when it was added to AMD CPUs (2011 ?), if you need to support those too (there's a list of AMD CPUs with SSSE3 on the Wikipedia page).

Comment: @PaulR Oh, thanks for the heads up! I'll be sure to look that up before I deploy.

Comment: @bgp2000 and Paul: there's a lot of loop overhead from doing `i/2` in the store instead of `i*2` in the loads.  In a double-rounding version of this, it went from 3.3 to 2.7 seconds (for 100M reps of 1024B each).  See my answer for performance-counter numbers  (which I kind of got carried away writing...)

Comment: @PeterCordes: that's interesting - the generated code (with either clang or gcc) seems fine - just a shift for the `/ 2` - still, it's a small loop, so maybe eliminating that will make a difference...

Comment: @PeterCordes: just tried a few experiments with clang - getting rid of the `/ 2` using various methods doesn't seem to make any difference - I see around 0.056 µs using Bjorn's test harness on a 2.6 GHz Haswell CPU.

Comment: @PaulR: Look at the 2nd asm block in my answer: there shouldn't be any shifts.  What you want is a scaled-index addressing mode on the loads `[rsi + rcx*2]`, and unscaled on the store `[rdx + rcx]`.  But for your answer with 4x `pmaddubsw`, yeah Haswell may bottleneck on port0, rather than the front-end.  You can't fold any of the loads into memory operands, though, so it's not that far off from a memory bottleneck.

Comment: Oh, Haswell only runs vector shifts on port0 (same as `pmaddubsw`), so yeah, that port0 is the bottleneck limiting you to one iter per 6 clocks.  You won't see any SnB/Haswell gains from tightening up the asm in your version (and probably not on Nehalem either), but it will make a significant difference on Skylake (where both those instructions can run on multiple ports).   Also maybe on Core2 where `psrlw` and `pmaddubsw` don't compete.  Probably not Ryzen where the front-end is wider (but pmadd and psrl throughput is 1c each), but maybe Bulldozer-family since shift and pmadd don't compete.

Comment: Just tested on Skylake: with `dst[i/2]` and clang4.0 (separate from the gcc7.1 times I added to my answer), I get 18.05G cycles for 100M iters with `-O3 -march=skylake -mno-avx`, but 12.12G cycles for the lower loop overhead version.  (And no branch mispredicts; it unrolled after inlining with size=1024).  It's as fast as gcc's output for my version!)

Comment: @PeterCordes: very nice!